# Strict filters creating nondescript error

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-qna-maker

Trying to utilize the QnaMaker filtering capabilities via the API as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/how-to/metadata-generateanswer-usage). When I make a request with the strict filters set, I receive the following response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "Unspecified",
    "message": "Something happened. Please retry after some time."
  }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at the App Insights instance that I had connected and the error was that a property didn't exist in the search index. Turns out I did not publish the KB, and the Azure Search index had not been updated. A better error message might be useful; App Insights is optional for QnA Maker.